# Excel sortable read-only/locked columns

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-2010, locked

How to enable sorting on locked cells (columns) in Excel 2010?

Tried many methods, including what seemed to be the correct method (i.e. protecting sheet and leaving `Sort` option checked) but still unable to sort.

Example:

```
  Question                   Answer
  ========                   ======
  What's your name?          Johnny
  How old are you?           703
```

I want Question column locked (so user can't change the question) and Answer column not locked (so user can enter answer!). But I want to be able to sort on the Question column.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've been able to achieve. Allows sorting but user can't select (therefore copy) any of the locked cells. If the range is converted to a table, the user will also be able to use 'Auto Filters' using this method.

Every step is required.

1. Unlock every cell (Right click > Format Cells > Protection >
   Locked)
2. Lock Every column you want locked (select entire column to
   lock every cell in column)
3. Unlock headers - select entire first row
   to unlock every cell in row

   *(this will allow sorting but also means
   the header text can be changed by the user) (not required if range has been converted to table)*
4. Add Editable range for
   the entire worksheet - Review tab > Allow Users to Edit
   Ranges > Range > New > A:AZ (the range you want to be sortable)
5. Protect worksheet - let them do everything but select locked cells (allowing select lock cells prevents sorting from working)

I imagine you can allow other permissions when protecting worksheet but I didn't need to so haven't tried.